# Liferay 6.2 bundled with jBoss connect to SQL Server 2012 with Windows Authentication

Tags: sql-server, jboss, liferay

I was asked to install Liferay 6.2 bundled with jBoss to connect to SQL Server 2012.
I don't understand why Liferay cannot connect to the database with the JDBC URL as follows:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DBSERVER/lportaldb;instance=lportal_DSN;useNTLMv2=true;domain=GLS.com.au
```

where,

- DBSERVER: server name
- lportalDB is database name
- lportal_DSN is data source name that I created in Control Panel/Administrative Tools/ODBC Data Sources (64-bit) and successfully tested the connection.

I've tried adding and removing some properties; such as useNTMLv2, I also put ntlmauth.dll to C:\Windows and C\Windows\SysWOW64 but the Liferay portal is still not be able to connect to the database.
Any idea on this is appreciated.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Sorry Lucky for my late response. That was something wrong with the connection or permission to the DBSERVER solved by the IT guys that I'm not supposed to know in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was check to the connection, LDAP, AD, DNS to the DBSERVER by IT group that fixed this issue. Regarding to the DB, it was changed to use SQL Server Authentication. 
The following JDBC URL was used with user sa and password:

`jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DBSERVER/lportaldb;instance=lportal_DSN;`